# Facebook timeline and avatar alignment

Tags: facebook, photos, facebook-timeline, avatar

Facebook prevents uploading images that are 160x160; the pictures must be uploaded at 180x180. Facebook then scales the picture down to 160x160 automatically. I would like to achieve a pixel-perfect alignment between the Facebook timeline cover image and the Facebook avatar but the scaling causes alignment issues. I cannot find exact steps that:

1. Are updated for the recent dimension changes.
2. Provide a template suitable for GIMP.
3. Walk through the Facebook picture upload process.
4. Describe how to crop the avatar to align with the cover.

When uploading the avatar to Facebook there is a crop tool but it doesn't show how many pixels are being cropped. It also doesn't say the size of the cropped image. This makes it difficult to determine whether Facebook will still scale the image down, or exactly what transformation will be made upon the image.

What are the exact steps (explained with screenshots would be great) to upload (1) a cover (at 851x315); and (2) an avatar (at requisite dimensions) such that the images are perfectly blended?

**Related**

- http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/new-larger-size-for-facebook-timeline-profile-pictures-buggy-rollout-or-bug/
- http://www.digitalkonline.com/blog/bid/52751/How-to-Blend-Your-Facebook-Cover-Image-with-Your-Profile-Picture
- http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/02/pimp-your-facebook-how-to-create-an-awesome-timeline-banner/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Great post is [here](http://blog.bullethq.com/how-do-i-create-a-facebook-timeline-cover-with-matching-profile-photo/).

> tl;dr Make the cover image 850px315px, cut your profile at 125px125 upload at 200x200px

Read the link above, also [here](http://blog.bullethq.com/how-do-i-create-a-facebook-timeline-cover-with-matching-profile-photo/), for the full text on what he did.

[image]

[image]

Disclosure: The link these are taken from is not on a page or site owned/operated by myself but rather found through Google. The images are owned by that page and are posted here in case that site goes away. However, the whole text isn't listed here to give that blog the love for detailing this out.